# How can I install Java libraries such as the jMonkey Engine system-wide?

Tags: java, libraries, system

I want to install the [jMonkey Engine](http://code.google.com/p/jmonkeyengine/) system-wide so that all users can use it.

Where do I put these files?

```
$ unzip -q jME2_0_1-StableDistribution.zip
$ tree -Fn jME2_0_1-StableDistribution/jME2_0_1-StableDistribution/
jME2_0_1-StableDistribution/jME2_0_1-StableDistribution/
|-- jme-audio.jar
|-- jme-awt.jar
|-- jme-collada.jar
|-- jme-editors.jar
|-- jme-effects.jar
|-- jme-font.jar
|-- jme-gamestates.jar
|-- jme.jar
|-- jme-model.jar
|-- jme-ogrexml.jar
|-- jme-scene.jar
|-- jme-swt.jar
|-- jme-terrain.jar
`-- lib/
    |-- jme-colladabinding.jar
    |-- jme-colladabinding-src.jar
    |-- jogl/
    |   |-- CHANGELOG.txt
    |   |-- COPYRIGHT.txt
    |   |-- gluegen-rt.jar
    |   |-- jogl.jar
    |   |-- LICENSE-JOGL-1.1.1.txt
    |   `-- native/
    |       |-- linux_amd64/
    |       |   |-- libgluegen-rt.so
    |       |   |-- libjogl_awt.so
    |       |   |-- libjogl_cg.so
    |       |   `-- libjogl.so
    |       |-- linux_i586/
    |       |   |-- libgluegen-rt.so
    |       |   |-- libjogl_awt.so
    |       |   |-- libjogl_cg.so
    |       |   `-- libjogl.so
    |       |-- macosx/
    |       |   |-- libgluegen-rt.jnilib
    |       |   |-- libjogl_awt.jnilib
    |       |   |-- libjogl_cg.jnilib
    |       |   `-- libjogl.jnilib
    |       |-- solaris_i586/
    |       |   |-- libgluegen-rt.so
    |       |   |-- libjogl_awt.so
    |       |   |-- libjogl_cg.so
    |       |   `-- libjogl.so
    |       |-- windows_amd64/
    |       |   |-- gluegen-rt.dll
    |       |   |-- jogl_awt.dll
    |       |   |-- jogl_cg.dll
    |       |   `-- jogl.dll
    |       `-- windows_i586/
    |           |-- gluegen-rt.dll
    |           |-- jogl_awt.dll
    |           |-- jogl_cg.dll
    |           `-- jogl.dll
    |-- jorbis/
    |   |-- copying.txt
    |   `-- jorbis-0.0.17.jar
    |-- junit/
    |   `-- junit-4.1.jar
    |-- lwjgl/
    |   |-- jinput.jar
    |   |-- LICENSE.txt
    |   |-- lwjgl.jar
    |   |-- lwjgl_util_applet.jar
    |   |-- lwjgl_util.jar
    |   `-- native/
    |       |-- linux/
    |       |   |-- libjinput-linux64.so
    |       |   |-- libjinput-linux.so
    |       |   |-- liblwjgl64.so
    |       |   |-- liblwjgl.so
    |       |   |-- libopenal64.so
    |       |   `-- libopenal.so
    |       |-- macosx/
    |       |   |-- libjinput-osx.jnilib
    |       |   |-- liblwjgl.jnilib
    |       |   `-- openal.dylib
    |       |-- solaris/
    |       |   |-- liblwjgl.so
    |       |   `-- libopenal.so
    |       `-- windows/
    |           |-- jinput-dx8.dll
    |           |-- jinput-raw.dll
    |           |-- lwjgl64.dll
    |           |-- lwjgl.dll
    |           |-- OpenAL32.dll
    |           `-- OpenAL64.dll
    |-- mvn-lib-install.sh
    `-- swt/
        |-- about_files/
        |   |-- IJG_README.txt
        |   `-- mpl-v11.txt
        |-- about.html
        |-- linux/
        |   `-- swt.jar
        |-- macosx-carbon/
        |   `-- swt.jar
        |-- macosx-cocoa/
        |   `-- swt_fake.jar
        `-- windows/
            `-- swt.jar

23 directories, 77 files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in the extension directory of your Java SDK. Since it will be loaded by the default classloader.

Basically you do the following steps:

- Copy all jars to a temporary folder, then

  `sudo cp *jar /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/ext`
- Copy all shared objects (*.so) of your computer architecture to a temporary folder, 
  then:

  `sudo cp *so /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386`

  or (if you are on amd64):

  `sudo cp *so /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64`

Answer (score 0):

Generaly speaking most manualy installed software would go in the /opt folder like xampp and Aptana studio for example there is a more expansive explanation here.

[What is the opt folder for](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/linux_filesystem/opt.html)

Comment: How will Java applications that need these libraries be able to find them in /opt?

Comment: Funnily enough it looks like the Jmonkey engine is going to be in the software center soon

Comment: Funnily enough it looks like the Jmonkey engine is going to be in the software center soon http://wwww.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10038906 . Just seen the engine featured on ubuntugamer looks cool. looking around the monkey forums it sounds like most people are using netbeans and manualy updating the library.path . The only reason I suggested the opt folder is the system doesn't change/update/overwrite anything that is put there it is entirely up to the admin what is there when making things more stable if more work.